# Aurelia `click` attribute that requires event target to be same as element

Tags: aurelia

I'm aware of `click.trigger` as well as `click.delegate` which work fine. But what if I want to assign a `click` event that should only trigger when the exact element that has the attribute gets clicked?

I'd probably do something like this were it "normal" JS:

```
el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target === el) {
        // continue...
    }
    else {
        // el wasn't clicked directly
    }
});
```

Is there already such an attribute, or do I need to create one myself? And if so, I'd like it to be similar to the others, something like `click.target="someMethod()"`. How can I accomplish this?

Edit: I've tried this which doesn't work because the callback function's `this` points to the custom attribute class - not the element using the attribute's class;

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class ClickTargetCustomAttribute {
    constructor (element) {
        this.element = element;

        this.handleClick = e => {
            console.log('Handling click...');

            if (e.target === this.element && typeof this.value === 'function') {
                console.log('Target and el are same and value is function :D');

                this.value(e);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Target and el are NOT same :/');
            }
        };
    }

    attached () {
        this.element.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    }

    detached () {
        this.element.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    }
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
<div click-target.bind="toggleOpen">
    ....other stuff...
</div>
```

(Inside this template's viewModel the `toggleOpen()` method's `this` is `ClickTargetCustomAttribute` when invoked from the custom attribute...)

I'd also prefer if `click-target.bind="functionName"` could instead be `click.target="functionName()"` just like the native ones are.

Comment: you could use `click.delegate=someMethod($event)`, then inspect $event object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use smth like `click.delegate="toggleOpen($event)"`. 
`$event` is triggered event, so you can handle it in toggleOpen

```
toggleOpen(event) {
    // check event.target here
}
```

Also you can pass any other value available in template context to `toggleOpen`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but instead of a `ClickEvent` I'm getting a `MouseEvent`. I guess it doesn't really matter as the `event.target` is still correct. One thing that annoys me with this approach though is that I need two separate toggleOpen:s - one that requires the event target to be the same as the clicked element, and one that behaves like normal. I also need a reference to the element the attribute was assigned to. It doesn't feel very dynamic imo. Is there no way to create something similar to `click.target="toggleOpen()` that would only fire `toggleOpen()` when `e.target===el`?

Comment: You can use `toggleOpen()` as normal, in that case you get `null value event` for normal behaviour

Comment: Ok that's true, I could check if an event is passed in and if so check the target. But is there any way to access the element that has the attribute without a `ref`? Because if I use a `ref` `toggleOpen` will be hard-coded to that element. Iykwim

Comment: you can try to pass `ref` value like `<span ref="myRef" click.delegate="toggleOpen($event, myRef)"></span>`

Comment: Another option is to fix context for `toggleOpen ` handler in `ClickTargetCustomAttribute `, try `<div click-target.bind="toggleOpenBinded">` where, `let toggleOpenBinded = toggleOpen.bind(neededContext)`

Comment: Ok I see, nice solution with passing in `ref`, haven't really used `ref` before. I guess this is the way to do it then. Thanks!